# Where is tf.contrib.layers.recompute_grad in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does TensorFlow 2.0 have any support for making a computation as "recompute during the gradient pass" to save memory?  TensorFlow 1.x has [tf.contrib.layers.recompute_grad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/recompute_grad), but `contrib` is gone in TF 2.0 and it doesn't look like anyone moved `recompute_grad`.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, they didn't move it. This is a big error on Google's part. I won't move to Tensorflow 2 for this reason. Recomputing gradients and creating memory efficient graphs is EXTREMELY helpful, if not vital.

Comment: Have you given up not moving to tensorflow 2?

Comment: I honestly haven't touched AI in over 3.5 years. Tensorflow has changed a lot since then, so I don't know at this point.